# Portable hard drive broken media

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

My portable hard drive fell on the on floor hard yesterday and stopped working, the hard light is flashing blue but my PC can't see it. I tried it with many machines, but the same it is not working. I showed it to a technical person and he told me that the issue is in the media, he listened to its sound and told me that, and that it is impossible to fix, is that correct? is there any hope to fix it anywhere any way?

Samsung s2 640 portable

Comment: You dropped a hard disk drive on the floor and now it doesn't work. Why is this a surprise? If your 'technical person' says it's broken, it's broken. Frankly, you didn't need someone to tell you that, did you? No - it can't be fixed. Drives are cheap - buy another.

Comment: may be it is simple as you said if it was empty but I contain some very important data i want to get, thanks for advice

Comment: Computer users fall into two groups: those that do backups and those that have never had a hard drive fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last chance, remove it from the case and try connecting it to a computer directly (it's probably a 2.5" SATA disk which connects without any converter). If Windows detect the device, see if you can see it in My Computer and see the files. In that case, take a copy of only the most important ones (if possible). If there are many folders you may have to do it one by one or even file by file. If the drive is detected but you cannot see it in My computer, it might have lost the partition data. This means your files are there but the partition table is corrupt and Windows cannot see them.

There are Data Recovery utilities (e.g. Get Data Back) that skip the partition table and search for data sector by sector. It can take hours on a damaged disk, but if lucky you could see a list of the folders and files at the end of the process. Again save only the important ones and discard the disk. If the computer hangs at boot time this is bad news! It tries to identify the disk but it is too damaged it cannot. Let's hope you are in the first two cases.

In last case just forget it. If the data are too important there are special Recovery companies that remove the readable layers, put them in another disk and retrieve as much data as they can, but you don't want to know the price... They are only reserved for VERY important data, not photos etc!